# Reflection - Casting an Object to it's unknown Superclass on the fly?

Tags: java, reflection, private

Hi I am in a situation where I have access to a class `House` Which extends `Foundation`(Please note the Class names are Hypothetical). And I have an object of type `House`, I would like to get the field `Foundation.width` which is set to private. I have come up with the code:

```
1.) Field list = houseObject.getClass().getSuperclass()
                                     .getDeclaredField("width");
2.) list.setAccessible(true);
3.) this.width = (double)list.get(foundationObject);
```

The problem is with line #3 I do not have access to a foundationObject, I have access to a houseObject, and since I do not truly know the Class of Foundation at compile time I cannot cast `(Foundation)foundationObject`.

Is there a solution to this? Thank you for your help.

---

A better way to word this question may also be: Can I get a non-static object of type Superclass from an object?

Comment: Why dont you try list.get(houseObject)?  I guess the accessibility change will cascade to sub classes.

Comment: That works, Thank You. Post as an answer And I'll accept.

Comment: i have added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `list.get(houseObject)`  The accessibility change will cascade to sub classes and hence the field will be accessible directly from `houseObject`.